# if statement in transact sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I need to enhance. This is what I have now.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [rw].[sp_EFT_NoticeXLS2] 
     (@Scope varchar(50)
    , @AcctPeriod char(6)
    , @CompanyID nchar(10)) 
AS ......
```

What I need to do is to pass a variable @GLsubacct to it only if @CompanyID is 0000.

I tried.....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [rw].[sp_EFT_NoticeXLS2] 
    (@Scope varchar(50)
   , @AcctPeriod char(6)
   , @CompanyID nchar(10) 
   IF (@CompanyID IS 0000) 
     @GLsubacct varchar(1000)) 
AS ....
```

but I am getting an error. I am not sure how to write the if statement. I need all the help I can get, thanks!

Comment: You can't conditionally accept parameters. You can make them optional by assigning them default values. Any conditional operations would be done inside the stored procedure, not its parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

You can setup the second variable to be "nullable"...making it "optional".

Then you can raise an exception if the rules don't follow.

Generic example:

```
Use Northwind
GO


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspDoSomething]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspDoSomething]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspDoSomething]
(
    @CustomerId varchar(12)
    , @PostalCode varchar(12) = NULL
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

if @CustomerId = 'ALFKI' AND @PostalCode IS NULL
BEGIN
    THROW 51000, 'You must supply a Postal Code with this @CustomerId.', 1;  
END


select * from dbo.Customers c 
where 
c.CustomerID = @CustomerId 
AND 
( @PostalCode IS NULL OR c.PostalCode = @PostalCode )


GO
/* examples */

exec [dbo].[uspDoSomething] 'ALFKI' , '12209'

exec [dbo].[uspDoSomething] 'ALFKI'

exec [dbo].[uspDoSomething] 'ANATR' , '05021'
```

Comment: Etiquette :: If this answer helps you resolve your issue (or another other answer), please mark it as "The Answer" and upvote (any) answers that were helpful.

Comment: How do I do that? I have asked this question before?

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use the `IF` statement below depending on what your Stored Procedure actually *does*, however what you're looking for is probably something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [rw].[sp_EFT_NoticeXLS2]
    @Scope varchar(50),
    @AcctPeriod char(6), 
    @CompanyID nchar(10),
    @GLsubacct varchar(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF @CompanyID = '0000'
    BEGIN

       -- CompanyID is 0000

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

       -- CompanyID is NOT 0000

    END
END
GO
```